# How to disable outlook highlighting the word 'congratulations' in the emailer development?

Tags: html, html-email, mailer

The feature highlights certain keywords with a different background color and text color. When hovering the keywords, a confetti animation appears. How can I turn it off in the HTML code itself?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

This has been flagged on Github - https://github.com/hteumeuleu/email-bugs/issues/59

Looks like:

```
<h1 class="foo">Congratulations</h1>
```

Will be transformed into:

```
<h1 class="x_foo"><span data-markjs="true" class="markim8ebdahz _2Th5e9ZyZUAFfXZXt-uLkQ">Congratulations</span></h1>
```

Adding this CSS will override the style Outlook is adding:

```
<style>
[class="x_foo"] span { background: inherit !important; color:inherit !important; }
</style>
```

However, it doesn't look like there is a way to stop the animation on hover.

Whether the solution works for you or not, or you get a different result - reporting back on that Github page would be helpful to the community.

Answer (score 0):

Putting a zero-width non-joiner character (‌) in the middle of the word should do it.